# SOAP UI Error in Windows system

Tags: soapui

I just formatted my system. Previously on the same system SOAP UI was working fine.

When I click on the button to get the results, after importing the WSDL, nothing happens. It is not even showing any error.

The SOAP UI error log:

```
2013-07-23 12:49:30,196 ERROR [errorlog] com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Request$SubmitException: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.RequestTransportRegistry$MissingTransportException: Missing protocol in endpoint [https:/cccp.ext.nokia.com/eai_enu/start.swe?SWEExtSource=WebService&SWEExtCmd=Execute&UserName=xxxxx&Password=xxxxx]
com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Request$SubmitException: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.RequestTransportRegistry$MissingTransportException: Missing protocol in endpoint [https:/cccp.ext.nokia.com/eai_enu/start.swe?SWEExtSource=WebService&SWEExtCmd=Execute&UserName=xxxxx&Password=xxxxxx]
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlRequest.submit(WsdlRequest.java:213)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.request.AbstractWsdlRequestDesktopPanel.doSubmit(AbstractWsdlRequestDesktopPanel.java:141)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.panels.AbstractHttpRequestDesktopPanel.onSubmit(AbstractHttpRequestDesktopPanel.java:750)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.support.panels.AbstractHttpRequestDesktopPanel$SubmitAction.actionPerformed(AbstractHttpRequestDesktopPanel.java:482)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
2013-07-23 12:49:41,837 ERROR [errorlog] java.lang.Exception: Failed to access [http://www.soapui.org/appindex/soapui_start.php?version=2.5]
java.lang.Exception: Failed to access [http://www.soapui.org/appindex/soapui_start.php?version=2.5]
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.components.BrowserComponent.navigate(BrowserComponent.java:127)
    at com.eviware.soapui.ui.URLDesktopPanel$Navigator.run(URLDesktopPanel.java:70)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.getStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setPage(Unknown Source)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.components.BrowserComponent.navigate(BrowserComponent.java:122)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 2):

I removed your password from log :-)

The endpoint has typo
**https:/cccp.ext.nokia.com/eai_enu/start**

Answer (score 2):

I think you are doing mistake to write your URL [https:/cccp.ext.nokia.com/....]
it should be [https://cccp.ext.nokia.com/.....]

Else you can check here [Request$SubmitException:](http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1860)